# Python unit testing with consistent random.seed using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, random, mocking, multiprocessing, pytest

I have a function in my code that calls a `multiprocessing.Pool`, and each worker process calls a function `generate_sensor` that uses `random.randint` and `random.choice` a number of times.  `generate_sensor` is in the file `seed.py`, which imports `random`.

I want to set a consistent random seed to ensure reproducible unit tests, and I'm having trouble, I *think* because of the use of multiprocessing, which means the order random is called isn't consistent.  Or maybe I just am trying to set the seed incorrectly.

---

The code in question, `my_module.py` in `main` contains something like this:

```py
num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() -1
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes)
tasks: list[tuple[seed.Seed, str, int, int]] = []
sensors: dict[str, sensor.Sensor] = {}

for i in range(num_processes):
    tasks.extend([(s, self.recSeq, seedSensPerProcess, i) for s in seeds])

for t in tasks:
    pool.apply_async(
        generate_sensor, t, callback=lambda result: sensors.update(
            [(r.seq, r) for r in result]
        ),
    )
pool.close()
pool.join()
return sensors
```

---

I'm trying to set a consistent seed in pytest for unit testing, to ensure a consistent result.

So far, I tried both of the following, to no success:

**Failed Approach 1:**

```py
def test_my_function() -> None:
    random.seed(0)
    out_sensors = my_module.main()
    print(out_sensors)
    assert False # so pytest will show print no matter what
```

This shows a different output every time, so the random imported by seed.py is not affected.

**Failed Approach 2:**

```py
def test_my_function() -> None:
    with patch("my_package.seed.random") as mock_random:
        mock_random = random.Random(0)

        out_sensors = my_module.main()
        print(out_sensors)
        assert False # so pytest will show print no matter what
```

This fails silently, and doesn't generate any output-- I'm guessing seed's imported random is no longer working.

---

Any idea on how to properly pass a random seed to the submodule?

Comment: Can you refactor `generate_sensor` to take an optional `Random` instance?

Comment: You mention that you're using a multiprocessing pool. Are you seeding `random` in the parent process, or in each subprocess? If the former, are you seeding it before or after spawning the processes, and are you using the fork start method or spawn/spawnserver?

Comment: @Brian61354270 -- the seed.py module is imported, and contains `import random`; the `generate_sensor` command calls a class from the seed module ( `seed.Seed`) that uses the random.randint and random.choice,  So, I'm not sure, but I don't think each process is importing it.  Not sure how imports are shuttled to subprocesses in multiprocessing, though, actually.

Comment: At what point does the `multiprocessing.Pool` get created? If you're using the spawn start method (default on Windows), then each subprocess is a fresh Python interpreter with its own, unique `random` global state. You'd need to run `random.seed` in each one (say using the `initializer` argument to `Pool`) to get them synced up. If you're using the fork start method (default on Unix), then the subprocesses should inherit the initial global start of the parent process, so would only only need to call `random.seed` once _before_ creating the pool.

Comment: For more on start methods and their implications, see [Contexts and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)

Comment: Also as a side note, before sure to not to specify `maxtasksperchild` when creating the `Pool`, since that will cause the worker processes to be periodically replaced with new ones with freshly seeded `random` states

Answer (score 0):

I was just mocking `random` incorrectly, trying to replace the whole module rather than methods.  Here's what worked:

```py
def test_my_function() -> None:
    with patch("my_package.seed.random") as mock_random:
        # mock_random = random.Random(0)  # Didn't work
        mock_random.randint = random.Random(0).randint  # works!
        mock_random.choice = random.Random(0).choice  # works!

        out_sensors = my_module.main()
        print(out_sensors)
        assert False # so pytest will show print no matter what
```